# Instagrapi recently showing HTTPError and UnknownError

Tags: python, instagram, instagrapi

I wrote a bot to help post some vacation photos, and it had been working well for a few months, but lately I've been getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/private.py", line 359, in _send_private_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/media/configure_sidecar/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/PostScheduler/with_instagrapi.py", line 133, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/PostScheduler/with_instagrapi.py", line 20, in main
    run_bot(path, post)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/PostScheduler/with_instagrapi.py", line 77, in run_bot
    bot.album_upload(paths=album,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/album.py", line 213, in album_upload
    raise e
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/album.py", line 202, in album_upload
    configured = (configure_handler or self.album_configure)(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/album.py", line 281, in album_configure
    return self.private_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/private.py", line 541, in private_request
    raise e
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/private.py", line 526, in private_request
    self._send_private_request(endpoint, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/private.py", line 448, in _send_private_request
    raise UnknownError(**last_json)
instagrapi.exceptions.UnknownError: Sidecar has 1 child. It requires 2 or more children.
```

Has something changed about instagram's API? Has something changed with instagrapi? I've tried looking at the project github but can't find any issues, reported bugs, or updates.